# How to turn on airline theme's background in vim?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, colorscheme, plugin-airline

I just started using `vim` and I installed [tpope/vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and then [vim-airline/vim-airline-themes](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes) plugin to use these themes. Then I changed my `.vimrc` to set up the `papercolor` theme, `powerline` fonts and line numbers permanently.

It looks like this:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

"Theme Section
let g:airline_theme='papercolor'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
set nu
```

The theme works and it's dope. But there's the main issue—there is no custom background, whatever theme I use.

Here you can look at the screenshot:
[image]

While the theme is supposed to look like this:
[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

I am using `KDE Konsole` and `zsh`

```
~ 
✦ ➜ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

This is my `.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/home/dagoth/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="spaceship"

plugins=(git)
plugins=(zsh-autosuggestions)
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE="fg=#ffbf00,underline"

ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks as expected. Airline is a statusline plugin (read `:help statusline`).

To set the editor's colorscheme, use `:colorscheme [name]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! it helped!